# Missing bracket Issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Am having trouble finding a problem in Xcode which keeps it from compiling. The error I get is `Expected ']' before ';' token`

Can you help me find the problem?

Here is the method in the implementation file:

```
- (IBAction) sendButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSString* themessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm %@ and feeling %@ about it.",
                                [activities objectAtIndex:[tweetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    [feelings objectAtIndex:[tweetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSLog(themessage);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You have ';' in 2nd line which should be ':

```
NSString* themessage = 
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm %@ and feeling %@ about it.",
              [activities objectAtIndex:[tweetPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]],
              [feelings objectAtIndex:[tweetPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]]
         ];
```

Answer (score 2):

(1) derp. what the other guy said;  your brackets are all outta whack w/your ;s

(2) never pass a string directly to NSLog();  if you want to just log a string, do `NSLog(@"%@", aString);`.

Comment: Sure --  the first arg to `NSLog()` is the format string. Any contained `%` sequences will be interpreted.  Try printing `NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@")`;  it'll crash.  If your string happened to have any random `%` sequences, it'll cause a similar crash.